# Dynamic textview add don't work properly in android

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

I have a method that adds a `textview` dynamically in a `linearLayout` everytime I click on a button, it works good in this case, but in some other cases i wanted to call it progmmatically without clicking on a button but it doesn't work.BUT when I click on the button again, the `textviews` appear.

This method is contained in a fragment by the way.

Here is my code :

```
private void add_part() {

        int width = bar.getWidth();

        int child_count = ((ViewGroup) bar).getChildCount();

        if (child_count == 0) {
            minus_btn.setEnabled(true);

            LayoutParams lparams = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                    LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);

            TextView part = new TextView(getActivity());

            part.setLayoutParams(lparams);
            part.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            bar.addView(part);
        } else if (child_count == 1) {
            minus_btn.setEnabled(true);
            View nextChild = ((ViewGroup) bar).getChildAt(0);

            LayoutParams newparams = new LayoutParams(width / 2,
                    LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
            nextChild.setLayoutParams(newparams);
            LayoutParams lparams = new LayoutParams(width / 2,
                    LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
            TextView part = new TextView(getActivity());
            part.setLayoutParams(lparams);

            bar.addView(part);
        } else if (child_count > 1 && child_count < 10) {
            minus_btn.setEnabled(true);
            for (int i = 0; i < child_count; ++i) {
                View nextChild = ((ViewGroup) bar).getChildAt(i);
                LayoutParams newparams = new LayoutParams(width
                        / (child_count + 1), LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
                nextChild.setLayoutParams(newparams);
            }
            LayoutParams lparams = new LayoutParams(width / (child_count + 1),
                    LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
            TextView part = new TextView(getActivity());
            part.setLayoutParams(lparams);
            bar.addView(part);
        }

    }
```

and I called it this ways :

```
add_part();
```

or

```
plus_btn.performClick();
```

Comment: Is there any errors in LogCat? What happens when you call `add_part`?

Comment: nothing, because it works but the result doesn't appear till i click again on the button which is kind of weird